XPath not working when value has equal operator using virt-xml
I'm running command:
cat ./xml | virt-xml --edit --xml ./tag1/tag2="a=b" > output.xml

it should add text a=b in tag2 but it is creating <tag2=a>b</tag2=a> which is incorrect.
I tried to escape equal character as well but no success.
How can I achieve this ?
the command I mentioned above should add text a=b in tag2 but it is creating <tag2=a>b</tag2=a> which is incorrect.
I tried to escape equal character as well but no success.

I don't know virt-xml, and its docs are a bit opaque to me.  However, I note that because the shell does quote processing, and nothing in a=b is special to the shell when that appears after the command name, the quotes in the command are insignificant.  The given command is equivalent to cat ./xml | virt-xml --edit --xml ./tag1/tag2=a=b > output.xml.

Does virt-xml even use XPath?  I find no mention of that on its manual page.

@JohnBollinger yes it uses xpath. when you see help of virt-xml --edit --help, it will tell to use xpath under --xml parameter.


I'm running command:
cat ./xml | virt-xml --edit --xml ./tag1/tag2="a=b" > output.xml

it should add text a=b in tag2 but it is creating <tag2=a>b</tag2=a>
which is incorrect. I tried to escape equal character as well but no
success.

The quotation marks in your command are interpreted by the shell.  virt-xml never sees them.  And if it did (for example, if you escaped them from shell interpretation), then I anticipate that it would interpret them as literal characters.  Similar applies to escaping one or more of the = signs.
The docs for virt-xml's --xml option are only summarized in that command's own manual page.  It refers to the docs for virt-install for a full explanation, which explains that --xml has sub-options.  You are, by default, using the xpath.set suboption to specify both node to edit and a value to set, but you can also specify the value to set separately via the xpath.value suboption.  Its docs include:

May help sidestep problems if the string you need to set
contains a '=' equals sign.

That's exactly your situation.
I anticipate, then, that you can obtain the result you want with
cat ./xml | 
  virt-xml --edit --xml xpath.set=./tag1/tag2 xpath.value=a=b \
  > output.xml

Or at least, that should resolve the particular you asked in the question.
